# How do I check if I have a base clearcase or UCM?

Tags: clearcase, cm-synergy

I am new to ClearCase . I have used rational synergy before.

We use ClearCase in our project for version control.
In my old project, I have used rational synergy, in which we used to create "tasks" for any modifications in the files.

I got to know that we have activities in ClearCase, which I want to use in our projects.
As of now, we just check-out the files and modify and checkin the changes.
But when I check my ClearCase --> Actions, I don't see the option `->WorkOn` to start creating an activity.

We are currently using the following version of ClearCase:

```
Version: 7.0.1.D061004
Build id: BALTIC_MR1.D070516
```

Please tell me if i need to install anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The "work on" would be ([`setact` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm)):

```
cd /path/to/your/ucm/view
cleartool setact anActivity@\yourPVob
```

To check on what activity you are currently working ([`lsact` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm)):

```
cd /path/to/your/ucm/view
cleartool lsact -cact
```

---

To check if a view is an UCM one or not:

```
cd /path/to/your/view
cleartool lsstream -cview
```

If there is a stream attached to your view, it is an UCM one. If not, it is a base ClearCase one (not this is separate for the nature of the view: dynamic or snapshot: you can have dynamic or snapshot view both for UCM or for base ClearCase).

another way is:

```
cleartool catcs
```

The config spec for an UCM view is automatically generated and quite more complex than the one for a base ClearCase view.

Comment: How Do I check if my view is a UCM view or not?

Comment: @user2256404 I have edited my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your ans VonC, one more doubt, I right click on one of the folders in my view. and the option UCM (below tools ) is disabled, Does this mean my view is not a UCM view?

Comment: If I want to chage this view or create further views with UCM , is the effort required more for the administrator?

Comment: @user2256404 it is possible that your view isn't an UCM one, but always rely on the command-line to make sure.

Comment: oki.. actually when i tried the command line from my view path, i got the error that cleartool is not recognised

Comment: @user2256404 you cannot convert a base ClearCase view into an UCM one. The easiest way is to create a separate UCM view, which means having an UCM project and UCM streams. Those Streams aren't branches (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5636931/6309). You need to define a Stream structure (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11677295/6309).

Comment: @user2256404 sure, you need to add your ClearCase/bin folder to your PATH. Here is an example on Unix: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21585596